# Show/hide with JavaScript on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

So far I have a code that when I press an element with class .coureNavToggle it reveals an element with .courseNavMenu class.
Could someone help me optimize this code so I could use this with multiple different buttons on multiple elements? For example, if I click on button A it opens element A, button B -> element B and etc. One option would be to copy and paste the code and change classes... But that's not what I need. As far as I understand this could be achievable by assigning a second class for both the button and element, but I have little knowledge in Javascript. Any help would be appreciated. And by the way, it's for Elementor(Wordpress).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
  var hbtn = $(".courseNavToggle");
  var hcon = $(".courseNavMenu");
  
   hcon.hide();
   hbtn.click(function(e) {
   var index = hbtn.index(this) 
   $(hcon).eq(index).slideToggle("slow");

   e.preventDefault();     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you'll need to put in something to assign the "clicked" element to the "target" element that you want to toggle. Luckily, JavaScript (and jQuery) make this really pretty easy. You can add any arbitrary data attribute to an element, and use that as a selector.

Take the following example for instance. I've added the `data-target-toggle` attribute to the first three elements. Two ID selectors and one class selector.

You can loop through each of the elements added to that variable, and grab the desired target element now. In that same loop, you can handle the click event to use the `slideToggle` function on the targets.

I've used a mix of id's, classes, and element types to show that using a method like this is truly abstract.

Just add `data-toggle-target="#some-id"` or `data-toggle-target=".some-class"` (or really, any valid query selector) to the element you want to click on, and make sure that you have that selector available, and it will slideToggle when you click on the element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var $hbtn = $('[data-toggle-target]');
  
  $hbtn.each(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-toggle-target');
    var $hcon    = $(selector);
    
    $hcon.hide();
    
    $(this).on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $hcon.slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle-target="#first">Toggle First</a>
<span data-toggle-target=".second">Toggle Second</span>
<button data-toggle-target="#third">Toggle Third</button>

<hr />

<div id="first">This is the ID first</div>
<h2 class="second">This is the CLASS second</h2>
<p id="third">This is the ID Third</p>
<a href="#" class="second">This is also CLASS second</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! But I have another question related to this! How could I make a close button that closes all open elements without targeting exact element each time for close button?
For example:
`<a href="#" data-toggle-target="#first">Toggle First</a>
<div id="first">This is the ID first <a href="#">Close<a/></div>`